# Azure AD returns Authentication_ExpiredToken on valid access token

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, access-token

I'm getting `Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the request.` when I call `https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/oauth2PermissionGrants?api-version=1.5` endpoint.

To prevent any stupid questions - Yes, I know that using `Microsoft Graph` is recommended instead of `Azure AD Graph`. I'm aware of it and I'm using it. But for my current case I need to request exactly `Azure AD Graph`.

Tests case:

1. I successfully login on `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=....` and get `code` in the response.
2. I successfully exchange `code` and get `access_token` on `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`.
3. I successfully make requests to any `Microsoft Graph` endpoint (ie `https://graph.microsoft.com/education/me/classes`).
4. I call `https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/oauth2PermissionGrants?api-version=1.5`.
5. I get the error `Authentication_ExpiredToken` `Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the request.`
6. I successfully make requests to any `Microsoft Graph` endpoint, so the `access_token` is valid.

Based on this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview, I can use this access token to access both `Microsoft Graph API` as well as `Azure AD Graph API`.

So, I'm using v2.0 which should work for those: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, I could not find a mention that you can use the token for both APIs. I also did not read any mentions that you could Azure AD Graph with v2 :) OAuth permission grants should be available from the beta endpoint for MS Graph so do you need access to it?

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code.Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) uses OAuth 2.0 to enable you to authorize access to web applications and web APIs in your Azure AD tenant. This guide is language independent, and describes how to send and receive HTTP messages without using any of our open-source libraries.

Comment: I don't want to use beta endpoint.There is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#oauth2permissiongrant-entity I'd like to use.

Comment: That documentation is for v1. You are using v2.

Comment: v2's support of APIs is limited at the moment. It will improve later. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? I can't use access_token got from `/oauth2/v2.0/token` to make requests to `https://graph.windows.net/...?api-version=1.5` endpoints?

Comment: Well, I have not tried that :) Some scopes do overlap between the two APIs, but usually you need a token per API since the audience in the token is set to always target one API.

Answer (score 21):

A token used to call the Microsoft Graph cannot be used to call the Azure AD Graph API.

When you look at the access token from Azure AD, there is a parameter called `aud` which stands for "audience". This property tells the API receiving the token the valid audience for that token.

If I own an API, "WebAPI1", and I get a token where the audience is something else, like "WebAPI2", I should reject that token, and not give the client access to my APIs. The reasons for this behavior should be obvious, but it causes major security issues if this check does not occur.

The `aud` value for the Microsoft Graph is `https://graph.microsoft.com/` while the `aud` for Azure AD Graph API is `https://graph.windows.net/`.

When requesting an access token, you need to specify which specific resource you want a token for using the `scopes` parameter. This and more information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes).

The solution here is to get a different access token for the different API, and your issues should be resolved.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thank you for such a great explanation! Now it's absolutely clear. The only thing that confused me is the response. It doesn't represent the problem correctly.

Comment: Totally agree there, but we would need more details about your authentication (like a raw token and a request trace) to know if it is an auth bug or just an error that appears before the other checks happen. For example, if at some point the graph checks for both expiration and aud, but does expiration first and your token is expired, then it would throw the first error without looking at all the rest... Just a hypothesis