# Retrieve group claims using _claim_sources returns The specified api-version is invalid. The value must exactly match a supported version

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, claims-based-identity

I want to retrieve groups claims for logged in user from Azure Active Directory. I've enabled groups retrieval in the application manifest in Azure Portal

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "All"
```

The number of groups exceeds a limit and I'm getting these claims instead:

```
_claim_names:   {"groups":"src1"}
_claim_sources: {"src1":{"endpoint":"https://graph.windows.net/12345678-0939-496d-b129-198edd916feb/users/{user-object-guid}/getMemberObjects"}}
```

**However when I make POST request to the endpoint specified in the claims, I'm getting:**

```
{
  "odata.error": {
  "code": "Request_DataContractVersionMissing",
  "message": {
    "lang": "en",
    "value": "The specified api-version is invalid. The value must exactly match a supported version."
    }
  }
}
```

How do I properly request the group claims? I could use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/getMemberObject, but it requires additional permissions and why whould there be another URI in the claims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should append the [version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api-quickstart#graph-api-versions) `?api-version=1.6` to the endpoint. See a complete code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/blob/d5c4d03938cc510a104b1a81b65472985df11a8f/WebApp-GroupClaims-DotNet/Utils/ClaimHelper.cs).

Comment: Now, I'm getting `Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the request.`, but I'm doing request right after login. How is that possible? What is the first guid in the uri, anyway?

Comment: Make sure you are obtaining a token for graph.windows.net (Azure AD API) and NOT for graph.microsoft.com (Microsoft Graph API). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483154/access-token-for-microsoft-graph-api-is-immediately-expired and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192583/azure-ad-returns-authentication-expiredtoken-on-valid-access-token

Comment: The GUID in the URI represents your domain. You can see it in Portal.Azure.com > Azure Active Directory > Properties. The GUID is there.